# iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013), I need to disable the camera completely

Tags: mac, camera

I've been looking around for a solution to disable the camera on these iMac's but coming up empty. One popular solution was going into the Quicktime folder and removing the ”QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer.component” but none of these machines have that file anyway. I'm in a correctional environment and these cameras needs to be removed or disabled. Since removing the physical camera ain't a option what else can I do?  Already someone figured out a work around the parental control and so that's why im here lol...  Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 0):

Temporary - tape over the lens.  More permanent - black nail polish over the lens or spike the lens (nail or icepick).  If you have the chops, you could try and disassemble and get to the CCD.  Not sure if this was a separate board on onboard the mobo.